# What's the purpose of the the 'when' selection when setting up keyboard shortcuts in eclipse?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, eclipse

I'm trying to set up some keyboard shortcuts in eclipse.

As well as requiring the binding, it also wants a 'when' selection from a combo box.

[image]

The question is - what is effect does this selection has. Which option can I choose to make my shortcut work when using the text editor in general?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'When' restricts the key binding to only working when a particular 'context' is active.

The 'In Dialogs and Windows' context covers just about everything so the key is always active.

'In Windows' is everything except dialogs.

'Editing Text' covers all text editors.

'Editing Java Source' covers just the Java source editor.

and so on.